# Does Linux copy NTFS File Permissions?

Tags: permissions, windows, file-copy, ntfs

I used a second HDD for data storage on my previous Windows installation (SSD). The problem is that when I try to access the files and folders Windows doesn't give me the right to do so.

Is there a Linux command to copy files without Windows NTFS-Permissions and attributes? Does "cp" for example even care about Windows/NTFS permissions?